# Error When Using Custom Open Graph Action

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-opengraph

I'm getting the error

> This action is not allowed to set a user message because this property
>   was not requested for approval.

For a custom Open Graph Action Type `westberksconnect:report` that I have submitted for approval.

I'm using Facebook.dll in C# .NET 4.0 and the code I'm using is below

```
        string strStatus = "";
        strStatus = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["status"];
        string Lat = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["lat"];
        string Lon = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["long"];

        string strToken = "XXXX";
        string strUpdateText = "We've received a report of a problem with " + strStatus + ".";  

        var client = new FacebookClient(strToken);

        Dictionary<string, object> WallPost = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
        WallPost.Add("message", strUpdateText);
        WallPost.Add("link", "http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=" + Lat + "+" + Lon);
        WallPost.Add("name", "View On A Map");
        WallPost.Add("picture", "http://www.westberks.gov.uk/images/common/googlemapicons/service_status/highway_009966.png");
        WallPost.Add("caption", "View a map of the location of the reported problem");
        WallPost.Add("description", "  ");
        WallPost.Add("problem", "http://samples.ogp.me/10150293874562522");

        var response = client.Post("/290203581014564/westberksconnect:report", WallPost);
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error and do they have a solution to it please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me. You neeed to submit your action for approval.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/

Unfortunately, i've been waiting for mine to be approved for a while now.